# Is it true that every non-nil object evaluates to true in objective-c?

Tags: objective-c

Is it true that every non-nil object evaluates to true in objective-c?  That is, is this:

```
if (thing) NSLog(@"yes");
```

identical to this:

```
if (thing != nil) NSLog(@"yes");
```

Empirically it seems to be true, even if `thing = @0`, but I can't find documentation that actually says this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The if checks for 0 (false) or any other number (true). Since your "thing" is basically an address (and therefore a valid number), it will evaluate to "true".

Answer (score 4):

It's true.

`@0` will be an `NSNumber` object with value 0, not address 0 (nil).

Answer (score 3):

Yes, every pointer that is not `nil` (or `NULL`) evaluates to true, just as in good old C. This is also true for objects like `NSNull`, which might sound like they would evaluate to false.

Answer (score 3):

Yes since Objective-C is a layer over C, the same rules apply.

In C every non-NULL variable/pointer evaluates to true, therefore that's also the case in Objective-C

Also `@0` represents a non-NULL pointer to a `NSNumber` therefore it correctly evaluates to true.

Answer (score 2):

```
((@0) && ([NSNULL null]) && (YES) && (thing) && (int a = 2))
```

evaluates to `TRUE` or `YES` respectively unless `thing==nil`